# Send email from Google-group-email

Tags: mail.app, gmail, accounts

In the mac mail app, it is possible to select *the from-email* in the dropdown menu.
[image: new email]

The available from-email adresses correspond to the added acounts.

**Adding accounts on a mac:**

```
In Yosemite: System Preferences -> Internet Accounts -> +
In Snow Leopard: Mail app -> Accounts -> +
```

To add an account, you need the email-address *and the password*.

**Adding accounts to a private gmail:**

```
www.gmail.com -> Settings -> Accounts and import -> Send mail as: -> Add another email address that you own
```

Here no password is required - You just have to reply to a confirmation email.

---

I want to be able to write from a Google-group-email on my mac. The problem is that there is no password for this email. (It is not an account, that you can log into).
**How can I add this email/account to my mac? -or solve the problem in an other way?** -so that I can write from the mac mail app, and not just my private gmail webmail.

---

*Additional informations about the Google-group-email:*
I am the administrator of a *Google Apps for Education* domain. I am the owner of the group in this domain. The group has three members. The group has an email-address: my_example_group@my_example_domain.com. It is not possible to log into into this account. The emails send to the address is automatically forwarded to the three members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are an "Owner" of said Google Group, you can just add the email as an "Alias" in the Mail.app.

```
Mail --> Preferences --> Accounts --> Select the account that "owns" the group i.e. "myfirst@email.com" --> Alias --> Edit Aliases
```

Simply add the email address of the owned Google Group.  In your example "mysecond@email.com".

Comment: Nowadays this is in `Mail --> Preferences --> Accounts --> <Account> --> Email Addresses -- > Edit Email Addresses...` 

Comment: The above resolution doesn't enable you to send from the group email - when you send from the group email is still shows up on the recipients side as being from the individuals email and not the group. Also how would you set it up so that you could also see emails which have been sent to the group inbox?